# GNU Radio and labview

Tags: labview, gnuradio, usrp, uhd

I am using a set of 4 N210 devices with SBX daughter boards where I need to perform a beamforming application. As I understood, the mentioned resync feature in the fractional PLL used is accessed through the UHD driver

Do Gnuradio or Labview support  "resync feature"?

Answer (score 1):

Both use UHD, and both have access to the functionality necessary to synchronize the LO frontends in all four SBXes:

- First, you will need to sync the N210's reference clocks – for that, you will need an external clock divider (e.g. an Octoclock) or GPSDOs.
- Then, you set a common device time relative to a common PPS signal. That can also come from four GPSDOs, or be sourced from a single device and split with a clock divider (Octoclock etc)
- Then, you can use timed commands to tune the frontends of the SBXes at exactly the same time, leading to a constant relative phase

For more information, the [UHD manual's page on LO synchronization](http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_sync.html#sync_phase_lo) will be of help!

Notice that you should use a recent version of UHD, i.e. keep your software as fresh as possible.

Comment: thank u alot , and what about matlab , does matlab support this function also?

Comment: All programs that talk to USRPs use the UHD driver. So yes, matlab's SDR toolkit has pretty extensive support for this too, but you should verify with the Mathworks.

Comment: I want to remove phase offest what should i do

Comment: The usual. Measure that offset, and multiply with a complex constant to get rid of it.